# Can you use same Minecraft / Microsoft account on different devices?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My child has Minecraft on the Nintendo Switch and has a Microsoft account so can play cross platform. He now also has bought Minecraft for the PS4. Can he use the same Microsoft account on the PS4 or do we need to set up a new one?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

I have one xbox live account and use it on 5 different devices.

I do not know if it will work on ps4 because I do not know anyone who owns a ps4 but it will probably work.

Answer (score 1):

He will be able to use the same account, he can log in on any Bedrock platform with that account.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can continue using the Minecraft/Microsof/XBox account on different devices. Just simply put up the info when logging in.